# Difference between Alamofire request and custom NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, http, post, alamofire

I post an `NSURLMutableRequest` to WebAPI using both Alamofire and self-defined method like :

**Alamofire**

```
 Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://www.webapi.com?path=Login", parameters: ["username": "myname", "password": "mypass"]).responseJSON { response in
// do something with returned data ...
}
```

**Custom**

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"http://www.webapi.com?path=Login")!)

let bodyData = "username=myname&password=mypass"
request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    // do something with returned data...

    }.resume()
```

I got correct result via Alamofire method but not my own method.

What did I do wrong comparing to the Alamofire post method?

Comment: you can open Alamofire.request method. alamofire code is open source.

Comment: When you say you got correct result; what is the incorrect result with NSURLRequest? Was it a crash, an error returned from the task, wrong data?

Comment: @keithbhunter the correct result is json formatted data and incorrect result is just `nil`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing parameter in alamofire in `["username": "myname", "password": "mypass"]` this format and in custom request `"username=myname&password=mypass"` in this format. so both have difference.

first one is json format and second one is string format.

So send data in json format from your custom request. take a `dictionary` of your parameters and convert it to data by using, `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject`

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I did try 
```let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(["username": "myname", "password": "mypass"], options: .PrettyPrinted);
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
request.HTTPBody = jsonData;``` 
and still got result nil.

Comment: option should be 0 instead of prettyprinted